# react components using css from non-imported

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, create-react-app

I am using create-react-app.

So I have overlapping class names e.g. `flex` being used by several components. However, it seems that when I include the css in one component, every other component now has visibility/usability of that css.

So I was wondering if there was a way to keep the css in scope or something to that effect.

Comment: That's expected behavior. You could write your CSS in JS, then apply styles by importing the JS file and accessing certain properties to apply certain styles to certain elements.

Comment: @AndrewLi I thought about that, but then I'd like to use the css queries like `@media` and `:hover` and such. And I find it odd that it would be expected behaviour when they're all for putting things into components.